# First instead of 1 when referencing

Tags: hyperref

I'm using an enumeration with labels assigned to the items.
Referencing to the items it works fine, but in some cases I would like to have "1st" or even "first" instead of just "1", with the former one not being that much of an issue, but as I'm also using hyperref I would like to have "1st" as a link and not only "1"st with the "1" being the link.
But the "first" is more important for me and it should also be a clickable link.
Does anyone have a solution for my issue?

see the MWE here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputec}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item1 \label{itm:1}
\end{enumerate}
Item \ref{itm:1} xyz...\\
The \ref{itm:1}st item xyz...\\
The first item xyz...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use \hyperref to create a link like \ref would do (the first argument is an optional argument, but I don't know why):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item1 \label{itm:1}
\end{enumerate}
Item \ref{itm:1} xyz...\\
The \ref{itm:1}st item xyz...\\
The \hyperref[itm:1]{first} item xyz...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Building on Ulrike’s answer,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\ordinalref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{\ordinalstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item1 \label{itm:1}
\end{enumerate}
Item \ref{itm:1} xyz...\\
The \ordinalref{itm:1} item xyz...\\
The first item xyz...
\end{document}
```

It doesn't work for nested items, unless you change the reference format.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that also looks like a great solution and an even more flexible one than Ulrikes as it's more automated when adding/removing items.
But is it possible to define the language for that to something different than english?

Comment: @Andreas `fmtcount` supports several languages, see its manual.

Comment: Took some time, but now I've got it working like I want it to, with the german genders, thank you VERY much!

Comment: This won't work if you change the numbering in the enumerate e.g. to \alph or \roman, or in a nested enumerate (which uses (a) as label). It would be imho better to use zref instead of refcount for something like this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer True, but referring to an ordinal in the case of a nonnumeric reference would sound strange.

Comment: In german writing "the first point" (der erste Punkt) for a point that is numbered as a) o i) would be quite natural - it would even work for an itemize. Also the code will also break if you add some formatting, e.g. `1)` or `Case 1`.